# Does Table size has an effect on Database performance when table is not in use?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, performance

Lets assume I have a table in my wordpress database which has thousands of rows and the table size would be more than 100mb.

Does this table has an effect on the whole performance of the database although there are no queries for this specific table?

Comment: short answer no, long answer, it could.

Comment: What is the point of a table in the database that never gets used?

Comment: The Table will be used when the user accesses the plugin in the wordpress backend. I am just interested if a big table has an effect on frontend performance or other plugins for example. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your data is stored. If your 100mb data is stored in closer blocks then it would not result in any change. If the data is more [Fragmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) and it results in other smaller tables using fewer blocks also getting fragmented then it could result in performance degradation.

For smaller tables there are times when the database caches the table and the disk storage mechanism does not matter when reading the results.

Comment: I have read your answer ten times. So fragmentation in sql results when stored rows were deleted and between the rows then there are empty blocks? Is it correct? in my case the plugin just ads new rows and deletes rows at the end when a specific date is exceeded. So there is no fragmentation or?

Comment: You will not be inserting all the data in one shot. If you have initially a 10mb size data records inserted to table A and the block size is say 8k as per database configuration. Storage required is 10000/8 = 1250 blocks. Suppose there comes three more tables B with 1 MB size, 1000/8 = 125 blocks will be gone. Then say you do 10 MB inserts to A followed by subsequent inserts to table B. Table A gets fragmented starting the second set of inserts. If you do deletion the deleted space can be reused for other tables.

Comment: Your database storage engine manages the CRUD operations that your perform. You do not issue the instructions directly.

Comment: Thank you! I think i got it. So every or most of the sql databases are fragmented. Is there a way to make a defragmentation?

Comment: You OS will have tools that perform defragmentation. Defragmentation is IO intensive so may have to perform it when nobody is using it. Also you should do that only when you have numbers to prove your point and a need to fix it. Any premature optimization without a proper analysis may result in more issues.

Comment: Thank your for this information and first impression how it works